# Program is blocking at ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, android, swing, sockets, serialization

My program is a simple server side java application receiving strings.
My program hangs at Input stream.
I read various discussion here and as pointed out i created output stream first and flushed it before creating an input stream.

Still i face the same issue.

SERVER SIDE CODE -JAVA SWING APP

```
//Server.java
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Server extends JFrame {
    JTextField txtenter;
    JTextArea txtadisplay;
    ObjectOutputStream output;
    ObjectInputStream input;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public Server() {
        super("SERVER");
        Container c = getContentPane();

        txtenter = new JTextField();
        txtenter.setEnabled(false);
        txtenter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sendData(e.getActionCommand());
            }
        });
        c.add(txtenter, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        txtadisplay = new JTextArea();
        txtadisplay.setEditable(false);
        c.add(new JScrollPane(txtadisplay), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(300, 150);
        show();
    }

    public void runServer() {
        ServerSocket ss;
        Socket s;
        int counter = 1;

        try {
            // create a seversocket
            ss = new ServerSocket(2222, 100);

            while (true) {

                // wait for the connection
                System.out.println("naval");
                txtadisplay.setText("Wating for the Connection...");
                txtadisplay.append("current IP:" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
                txtadisplay.append("current PORT:" + ss.getLocalPort());

                // establishing connection
                System.out.println("naval2");
                s = ss.accept();
                output = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                output.flush();
                input = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                System.out.println("naval3");
                txtadisplay.append("Conection" + counter + "receivedfrom:" + s.getInetAddress().getHostName());
                System.out.println("naval4");
                // getting input/output

                System.out.println("naval5");
                output = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                output.flush();
                input = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                System.out.println("staream created");
                System.out.println("naval6");
                // processing connection
                String message;

                do {
                    txtadisplay.append("under DO loop");
                    message = (String) input.readObject();
                    txtadisplay.append("" + message);
                    txtadisplay.setCaretPosition(txtadisplay.getText().length());
                } while (!message.equals("CLIENT>>>TERMINATE"));

                txtadisplay.append("User Terminated Connection...");

                input.close();
                s.close();
                ++counter;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public void sendData(String s) {
        try {
            output.writeObject("SERVER>>>" + s);
            txtadisplay.append("SERVER>>>" + s);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Server ser = new Server();

        ser.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void WindowClosing(final WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        ser.runServer();
    }

}
```

CLIENT SIDE CODE - ANDROID APP

```
package info.androidhive.speechtotext;


import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import static java.sql.DriverManager.println;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * Declarations
     */
    private TextView txtSpeechInput;

    private ImageButton btnSpeak;

    String str;

    private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;

    private String serverIpAddress = "";

    private boolean connected = false;

    TextView textIn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        txtSpeechInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput);
        btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        // hide the action bar
        getActionBar().hide();

        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                promptSpeechInput();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Showing google speech input dialog
     */
    private void promptSpeechInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Receiving speech input
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                    ArrayList<String> result = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
                    str = result.get(0);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    Log.d("1- naval", " client oncreate");

                    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
                    textIn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textin);
                    /**
                     * Setting the text box with default value
                     */
                    textIn.setText(str);
                    Log.d("settext", " 2-naval");
                    /**
                     * Here we need to fill in textin from MainActivity,
                     * where we received the speech API text
                     */
                    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                                  @Override
                                                  public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                                      if (!connected) {
                                                          serverIpAddress = "192.168.0.4";
                                                          if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                                                              Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                                                              cThread.start();
                                                          }
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }
                    );


                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr,2222);
                PrintWriter out = null;
                out.println(str);
                connected = true;
                while (connected) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                        out = new PrintWriter(
                                new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                                        socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                        // WHERE YOU ISSUE THE COMMANDS
                        // out.println("Hey Server!");
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                    }
                }
                socket.close();
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
                connected = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your client side code?

Comment: Updated original post

Comment: What does 'hangs at input stream mean? Why are you creating two ObjectOutputStreams on the same socket? Why are you trying to read data that was written with a PrintWriter with an ObjectInputStream? Why are you surprised that an input stream blocks when you aren't sending anything to it? Why aren't you reading anything in the client from either of the two object output streams in the server? What's the question?

Comment: `PrintWriter out = null; out.println(str);` -> NullPointer

Comment: For a start, your client is sending text while your server is expecting serialised objects - your client should be sending Strings to an ObjectOutputStream. Once this is fixed, check that your client is definitely sending data (using logging or step-through debugger). Your server can be expected to block until it actually receives something.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by fellow forum mates . Changing to outputStream on Client side helped .
Thanks..

Just a quick query : Though the application is working fine.There is a lag of 1-2 seconds for a message to reach  from android app to java desktop app. Is it normal or i need some fine tuning.

CODE

```
Android Client

MainActivity.java

package info.androidhive.speechtotext;


import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import static java.sql.DriverManager.println;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * Declarations
     */
    private TextView txtSpeechInput;

    private ImageButton btnSpeak;

    String str;

    private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;

    private String serverIpAddress = "";

    private boolean connected = false;

    TextView textIn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        txtSpeechInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput);
        btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        // hide the action bar
        getActionBar().hide();

        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                promptSpeechInput();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Showing google speech input dialog
     */
    private void promptSpeechInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Receiving speech input
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                    ArrayList<String> result = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
                    str = result.get(0);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    Log.d("1- naval", " client oncreate");

                    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
                    textIn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textin);
                    /**
                     * Setting the text box with default value
                     */
                    textIn.setText(str);
                    Log.d("settext", " 2-naval");
                    /**
                     * Here we need to fill in textin from MainActivity,
                     * where we received the speech API text
                     */
                    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                                  @Override
                                                  public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                                      if (!connected) {
                                                          serverIpAddress = "192.168.0.4";
                                                          if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                                                              Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                                                              cThread.start();
                                                          }
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }
                    );


                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        Socket socket = null;


        public void run() {
            try {
                socket = new Socket("192.168.0.4", 2222); //use the IP address of the server

                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                oos.writeObject(str);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

                if (socket != null) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

JAVA SERVER

```
//Server.java
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Server extends JFrame {
    JTextField txtenter;
    JTextArea txtadisplay;
    ObjectOutputStream output;
    ObjectInputStream input;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public Server() {
        super("SERVER");
        Container c = getContentPane();

        txtenter = new JTextField();
        txtenter.setEnabled(false);
        txtenter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sendData(e.getActionCommand());
            }
        });
        c.add(txtenter, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        txtadisplay = new JTextArea();
        txtadisplay.setEditable(false);
        c.add(new JScrollPane(txtadisplay), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(300, 150);
        show();
    }

    public void runServer() {
        ServerSocket ss;
        Socket s;
        int counter = 1;

        try {
            // create a seversocket
            ss = new ServerSocket(2222, 100);

            while (true) {

                // wait for the connection
                System.out.println("naval");
                txtadisplay.setText("Wating for the Connection...");
                txtadisplay.append("current IP:" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
                txtadisplay.append("current PORT:" + ss.getLocalPort());

                // establishing connection
                System.out.println("naval2");
                s = ss.accept();
                txtadisplay.append("Conection" + counter + "receivedfrom:" + s.getInetAddress().getHostName());
                output = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                output.flush();
                input = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                System.out.println("naval3");

                System.out.println("naval4");
                // getting input/output


                String message;

                do {
                   // txtadisplay.append("under DO loop");
                    message = (String) input.readObject();
                    txtadisplay.append("" + message);
                    txtadisplay.setCaretPosition(txtadisplay.getText().length());
                } while (!message.equals("CLIENT>>>TERMINATE"));

                txtadisplay.append("User Terminated Connection...");

                input.close();
                s.close();
                ++counter;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public void sendData(String s) {
        try {
            output.writeObject("SERVER>>>" + s);
            txtadisplay.append("SERVER>>>" + s);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Server ser = new Server();

        ser.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void WindowClosing(final WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        ser.runServer();
    }

}
```

Comment: Changing to *`ObjectOutputStream`* in the client helped. Why are you opening an `ObjectInputStream` in the client and never reading from it? Why are you sending objects from the server that are never being read by the client?